# How do I add the contents of an iterable to a set?

Tags: python, set, conventions, iterable

What is the ["one [...] obvious way"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) to add all items of an iterable to an existing `set`?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

You can add elements of a `list` to a `set` like this:

```
>>> foo = set(range(0, 4))
>>> foo
set([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> foo.update(range(2, 6))
>>> foo
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Just looked back at my interpreter session and I actually tried this, but thought that it had added the whole list as an element of the set because of the square brackets in the representation of the set. I had never noticed before that they're represented like that.

Comment: That representation allows you to paste it right back in an interactive session, because the `set` constructor takes an iterable as its argument.

Comment: Note that the representation is just e.g. `{1, 2, 3}` in Python 3 whereas it was `set([1, 2, 3])` in Python 2.

Answer (score 54):

For the benefit of anyone who might believe e.g. that doing `aset.add()` in a loop would have performance competitive with doing `aset.update()`, here's an example of how you can test your beliefs quickly before going public:

```
>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"it=xrange(10000);a=set(xrange(100))" "a.update(it)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 294 usec per loop

>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"it=xrange(10000);a=set(xrange(100))" "for i in it:a.add(i)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 950 usec per loop

>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"it=xrange(10000);a=set(xrange(100))" "a |= set(it)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 458 usec per loop

>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"it=xrange(20000);a=set(xrange(100))" "a.update(it)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 598 usec per loop

>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"it=xrange(20000);a=set(xrange(100))" "for i in it:a.add(i)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.89 msec per loop

>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"it=xrange(20000);a=set(xrange(100))" "a |= set(it)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 891 usec per loop
```

Looks like the cost per item of the loop approach is over THREE times that of the `update` approach.

Using `|= set()` costs about 1.5x what `update` does but half of what adding each individual item in a loop does.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the set() function to convert an iterable into a set, and then use standard set update operator (|=) to add the unique values from your new set into the existing one.

```
>>> a = { 1, 2, 3 }
>>> b = ( 3, 4, 5 )
>>> a |= set(b)
>>> a
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Using `.update` has the benefit that the argument can be any iterable —not necessarily a set— unlike the RHS of the `|=` operator in your example.

Comment: Good point.  It's just an aesthetic choice since set() can convert an iterable into a set, but the number of keystrokes are the same.

Comment: I have never seen that operator before, I'll enjoy using it when it pops up in the future; thanks!

Comment: @eipxen: There's `|` for union, `&` for intersection, and `^` for getting elements that are in one or the other but not both. But in a dynamically typed language where it's sometimes difficult to read the code and know the types of objects flying around, I feel hesitant to use these operators. Someone who doesn't recognize them (or perhaps doesn't even realize that Python allows for operators like these) could be confused and think some weird bitwise or logical operations are going on. It'd be nice if these operators worked on other iterables, too...

Comment: Ran some time tests on this versus `.update()` and add individual elements in a loop. Found that `.update()` was faster. I added my results to this existing answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4046249/901641

Answer (score 8):

Just a quick update, timings using python 3:

```
#!/usr/local/bin python3
from timeit import Timer

a = set(range(1, 100000))
b = list(range(50000, 150000))

def one_by_one(s, l):
    for i in l:
        s.add(i)    

def cast_to_list_and_back(s, l):
    s = set(list(s) + l)

def update_set(s,l):
    s.update(l)
```

results are:

```
one_by_one 10.184448844986036
cast_to_list_and_back 7.969255169969983
update_set 2.212590195937082
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use list comprehension.**

Short circuiting the creation of iterable using a list for example :)

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> 
>>> k = x.__iter__()
>>> k
<listiterator object at 0x100517490>
>>> l = [y for y in k]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> 
>>> z = Set([1,2])
>>> z.update(l)
>>> z
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>>
```

[Edit: missed the set part of question]

Comment: I don't see any sets? Am I missing something?